# How to give a unique id to a test object in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

```
context 'with dish available to pre-order' do
let!(:dish) { create :dish, chef: chef }
let!(:dish2) { create :dish, chef: chef2}

it 'should show dish' do
  Time.zone = 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'
  t = Time.zone.local(2016, 7, 25, 20, 30, 0)
  Timecop.travel(t)
  visit '/'
  set_delivery_time
  select_delivery_area_by_chef dish.chef
  visit '/preorders'
  expect(page).to have_content('PREORDER MENU')

  within('div#dishes-container') do
    expect(page).to have_xpath("//img[@src=\"#{dish.image.small}\"]")
    expect(page).to have_content(dish.description)
    expect(page).to have_content(dish.name)
    expect(page).to have_content(dish.price)
    expect(dish).to have_content("Add to Cart")
    expect(dish2).to have_content("Pre-Order")
    expect(current_path).to eq(preorders_path)
  end
end

1) Visitor can see preorders with dish available to add to cart, preparation time over 1 hour should show dish
 Failure/Error: expect(dish).to have_content("Add to Cart")
   expected to find text "Add to Cart" in "Dock Bogisich"
 # ./spec/features/visitor/preorders/list_of_preorders_spec.rb:129:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/features/visitor/preorders/list_of_preorders_spec.rb:124:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I am trying to get rspec to check if specifically dish has 'add to cart' content and dish 2 to have 'pre-order' content. How can I get Rspec to check it? Is it possible to give them both a unique id and call it out here?

Answer (score 0):

In your view assign ids to both the buttons. Something like:

```
<button id="add_to_cart-{dish.id}"> ADD to Cart </button>
<button id="pre-order-{dish2.id}"> Pre-Order </button>
```

Than in spec:

```
add-cart-btn = "button#add_to_cart-#{dish.id}"
with_in add-cart-btn do
  page.should have_content 'Add to Cart'  
end
```

Same for the Pre-order!